# ray.interstectObjects not intersecting correctly after geometry is dynamically modified

Tags: three.js

My ray.intersectObjects works really well with the objects in my scene until I dynamically modify the geometry of the object.  Although the renderer is showing the objects as being modified (vertices moved and faces changed), when an intersect is tried on the modified object, it produces strange results.  I need the intersect to work even on the modified geometry!

To help debug and track how the intersect is working in my scene, I've added a function: makeMiniSphere().  This makes a new sphere object in the scene at the point where the intersection occurs.  Using this, you can see that after the cube is modified, sometimes the intersect hits the cube and sometimes it goes right through (mostly the faces that have been modified).  It isn't a random problem, but the more you click around the modified cube, the more you can see a pattern develop.  It is almost as if the renderer for the visuals of the scene know which direction the cube was modified, but the ray.intersectObjects thinks that it has been modified in a different direction!

Here is a link to the test website: http://www.littledrop.net/html/cadiverse/HelloWorld.html

Directions to show problem:

1. Left click on cube to show intersect points.  Mini spheres will be created wherever Three.js sees an intersect.  The color of the selected object will change to yellow if not already selected.
2. Click on any face of the cube.  This will A. Turn it yellow if it isn't already yellow.  B. It will select the face of the cube, although the selected face won't look any different from the rest of the cube.
3. Press the "Right" arrow key to move the selected face to the right.  This will dynamically change the geometry of the cube.

Now try to click on the cube--especially in the area that it has been modified.  Again the Mini spheres will show where the software thinks the intersects are occurring.

Here is the intersect code:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown (event)
{
// the following line would stop any other event handler from firing
// (such as the mouse's TrackballControls)
//event.preventDefault();   
mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
document.getElementById('message1').innerHTML = window.innerHeight;
var isinworkingarea = window.innerHeight-menubarh;

if (event.clientY<=isinworkingarea)
{
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
    //var ray = new THREE.ReusableRay();
    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );
    // create an array containing all objects in the scene with which the ray intersects
    //  use this to select anything in the scene: 
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( scene.children );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 )
    {
        if (cadjectNow)
            cadjects[cadjectNow].material.color.setHex(cadjects[cadjectNow].oldColor);
        if (intersects[0].object.cadNum)                                                
            cadjectNow = intersects[0].object.cadNum;
        SELECTEDface=intersects[0].face;
        if (cadjectNow)
            cadjects[cadjectNow].material.color.setHex( selectColor );
        document.getElementById('message1').innerHTML = cadjects[cadjectNum].cadNum;

        ///// Information about selected /////
        var facestring = intersects[0].face.a  + " " + intersects[0].face.b + " " + intersects[0].face.c;
        if(intersects[0].face instanceof THREE.Face4) 
        {
            facestring=facestring + " " + intersects[0].face.d;
        }

        copyGeometry=cadjects[cadjectNow].geometry;
        //makeCopy(copyGeometry,cadjects[cadjectNow].position.x,cadjects[cadjectNow].position.y,cadjects[cadjectNow].position.z);
        makeMiniSphere(intersects[0].point.x, intersects[0].point.y, intersects[0].point.z);

        document.getElementById('message1').innerHTML = facestring;
        //document.getElementById('message2').innerHTML = cadjects[cadjectNow].geometry.vertices[SELECTEDface.a].x + " " + cadjects[cadjectNow].geometry.vertices[intersects[0].face.a].y + " " + cadjects[cadjectNow].geometry.vertices[intersects[0].face.a].z;
        document.getElementById('message2').innerHTML = intersects[0].point.x + " " + intersects[0].point.y + " " + intersects[0].point.z;

    }
}
}
```

Here is the modify code:

```
if ( keyboard.pressed("right"))
{
    document.getElementById('message1').innerHTML = mouseMode;
    cadjects[cadjectNow].geometry.vertices[SELECTEDface.a].x+=10;
    cadjects[cadjectNow].geometry.vertices[SELECTEDface.b].x+=10;
    cadjects[cadjectNow].geometry.vertices[SELECTEDface.c].x+=10;
    if(SELECTEDface instanceof THREE.Face4) 
    {
        cadjects[cadjectNow].geometry.vertices[SELECTEDface.d].x+=10;
    }
    cadjects[cadjectNow].geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    cadjects[cadjectNow].geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
    cadjects[cadjectNow].geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
}
```

Thank you to everyone who has posted past questions and given the answers.  By perusing past questions, I've been able to get this far---so you guys have already been a great help.  Thanks in advance for help on this one.  (As this is my first question to post here, any suggestions on how to better present a question are also more than welcome.)

Update (3/21/13)--I've migrated to r57 as suggested and the updated code is shown above.  I've also debugged it so that it is working at least as well as it was before.  So now the geometry is still visually being changed dynamically, but the intersect is not detecting the change properly.  Thanks @WestLangley for the encouraging posts so far.

Comment: You are using a version of the library that is a year old. Please update to the current version r.57 and re-post if you are still having problems.

Comment: Good point, @WestLangley.  I'll try that this afternoon!

Comment: I've updated to r57 and am now working migration <https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration > .  Will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Okay, I've migrated to r57 and have no errors. :)  The problem is that the cube is not showing any deformation (visually) even though the intersect is showing that it has been modified.  I've used the latest webgl_geometry_dynamic.html as an example to follow to know what I should have in the code so that it will render the changes in geometry--but to no avail.  Specific question then would be: what exactly do I need in my code 1. during the cube creation and 2. when the vertices have been modified for the renderer to show the changes in geometry? (vertices.needsUpdate=true; , etc.)  Thanks

Comment: You need to debug your code. I can't help you with that. Study the [Wiki article](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates).

Comment: Thanks, @WestLangley for the encouragement and direction.  It has been debugged and it is visually updating correctly, but now I'm back to the original problem with the intersect! :)

Comment: Update the boundingSphere of the geometry after you modify it. Update the face normal of any face you change. Raycaster will not work correctly if your four-sided faces are no longer planar. Google non-planar and three.js. Study the Raycaster code so you understand how it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now working correctly.  Here is how I did it (thanks to Westlangley for guidance).

1. Upgrade Three.js to latest revision (r57 from r49).
2. Migrate my present code to work with r57.
3. Remove all former code attempting to update the object.
4. Added the following code to "modify object" section:

   cadjects[cadjectNow].geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
   cadjects[cadjectNow].geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
   cadjects[cadjectNow].geometry.computeFaceNormals();
   cadjects[cadjectNow].geometry.computeVertexNormals();
   cadjects[cadjectNow].geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

Comment: Strange but true -- computeBoundingSphere() is indeed required. One would assume AABBs / planes would ordinarily be enough for this but apparently not in three.js.

Comment: i just spent 3 hours trying to solve this. and all i was missing was computeBoundingSphere, thanks for the answer

Comment: ComputeBoundingSphere!? aaah id have thought computeBoundingBox would have been similar enough / worked. thanks!

Comment: For me to get it working, R93 I needed to do: `geometry.computeBoundingBox()`

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue with a modified BufferGeometry.

I got raycasting working by calling `geometry.computeBoundingSphere()` and `geometry.computeBoundingBox()` after modifying the array with vertex positions.

Setting `verticesNeedUpdate` was not needed.

Running r112.